# How to generate a "static" weighted random samples using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random

I would like to generate some static weighted random samples using Matlab. I am now using `randsample()` to achieve weighted random samples, the command is as follows:

```
P = randsample([1 2 3 4],12,true,[0.15 0.35 0.35 0.15]);
```

However, `P` will change every time when I run this command...

Any thoughts on how to make `P` static? Thanks in advance!

Comment: look at the help for `rng` for information on how to set the seed for the random number generator

Comment: Thanks for the input!  I'm also using randi() to generate random integers, I'm hoping to keep that dynamic. Can I make randsample() static and randi() dynamic at the same time by using rng()?

Comment: Sure! Just save the existing seed in a variable before you call randsample. Set it to some constant, call randsample, and then set the seed back to the saved value.

Comment: Got it, thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Put the randsample bit in its own section using "%%".

run the next section - using ctrl+enter - (with the rest of your code in it) so that P is not initialized again.

```
%% Initialize P
P = randsample([1 2 3 4],12,true,[0.15 0.35 0.35 0.15]);
%% The Rest of my code
[... insert code here]
```

Comment: This is a good answer if the result doesn't have to be *reproducible* between sessions, but a general solution should make us of the random seed, as [@transversalitycondition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270081/how-to-generate-a-static-weighted-random-samples-using-matlab#comment54341317_33270081) suggested.